# After installing Office365 can you go back to Office 2008 (without the CD)

Tags: microsoft-office

I got this laptop from my dad and don't have the Microsoft Office 2008 CD which is what he had installed when he gave it to me to use. Now I've got a client that wants me to do some freelance work and sent me to Microsoft Exchange and the first thing it wants me to do in the Exchange is install Office365. The client mentioned very briefly that he would get me the software if necessary but he wasn't specific about what software. Now that I see it my concern is after the job is done I'll be left with a monthly bill to have Office.

Will it be possible to go back to Office 2008 without having the CD?

Comment: Sure - All you have to is restore the laptop using the factory restore image.

Comment: Um doesn't that imply Office came on the computer? For all I know my dad bought the software and installed it at some point. Far more likely in fact since I'm not on a Windows computer. Not to mention won't that wipe all of my other software as well?

Comment: You can make your own image (using free software). Store that to restore it as needed, or keep it as a backup. Just make sure only to image the OS partition and not the whole drive or data partition.